# why does backbone think I'm treating an object like a function?

Tags: backbone.js

Adding Backbone to a Rails app, I created a post model inside an app namespace like this

```
var app = {

 this.models.post = new app.Models.Post();
```

In the router, I created the following route

```
 "posts/:id": "postDetails"
```

When I navigate to /posts/4, I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` error when I try to call fetch on the model like this

```
 postDetails: function (id) {
        console.log(id);
        var post = new app.models.post({id: id});
        this.post.fetch({
            success: function (data) {

                $('#content').html(new PostView({model: data}).render().el);
            }
        });
    }
```

According to the Backbone docs http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch, I should be able to call fetch on a model to retrieve the data from the server. Why does Backbone think I'm treating an object like a function?

Comment: what line exactly causes the error?

Comment: actually, it's this line `var post = new app.models.post({id: id});`. I changed it to `var post = new app.Models.Post` and it told me `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fetch' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
this.models.post = new app.Models.Post();
```

to, presumably, set `app.models.post` to an *instance* of the `app.Models.Post` model. Then you try to do this:

```
var post = new app.models.post({id: id});
```

But you can only use the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) on a function:

> `new constructor[([arguments])]`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `constructor`
>   A function that specifies the type of the object instance.

You probably want to say:

```
var post = new app.Models.Post({ id: id });
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've declared `post` as a local variable `var post`, but then tried to access it as a member `this.post`.  You need either this:

```
this.post = new app.models.post({id: id});
this.post.fetch({ ...
```

Or this:

```
var post = new app.models.post({id: id});
post.fetch({ ...
```

(The difference being that a local variable `var post` is declared in transient scope and thrown away after `postDetails` completes; while instance variable `this.post` gets added to the Router object and will typically live for the whole lifetime of the application.)